# gRPC Python Request Streaming RPC handle connection loss

Tags: python, grpc

For a request streaming gRPC python client no error is thrown on connection loss.

```
import grpc
import time
from datetime import datetime

from pb import pypong_pb2, pypong_pb2_grpc

def yielder():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield pypong_pb2.RequestStreamRequest(message=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

def run_client():

    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('172.10.10.3:50051')
    client = pypong_pb2_grpc.PyPongStub(channel)
    client.RequestStream(yielder())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_client()
```

I test this by disconnecting the network at the client or server side, in both cases the client does not react to the change. I would expect an error to be raised if a stream message cannot be delivered.

Comment: Try enable keepalive time and timeout.